# WSO2 BAM event tracing and correlation

Tags: wso2, wso2-bam

I'm interested in WSO2 Business Activity Monitor.
I read several documentations but I still wondering if WSO2 BAM can handle my following Business Activity Monitoring use case:

Example

System A produces an event with a new transactionID "ORK78954".

System B produces (1min later) another event the the same transactionID "ORK78954"

System C doesn't produce an event with transactionID "ORK78954" in the next 5 minutes.

Of course, I don't know which transactionsIDs are used. WSO2 has to use RegEx etc. on the transactionID field on the event.
System A, B, C not inside WSO ESB, they "only" fire events into BAM.

Can WSO2 alert me, that System A produced an event (with a transactionID "ORK78954") that never reached System C?

When not out of the box, do you think it is possible to write an own CEP window for this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

I got the following answer from WSO2:

*This requirement can be supported by the WSO2 Complex Event Processor(CEP) or through the embedded CEP component of the WSO2 Business Activity Monitor (BAM). Each external system can publish the relevant event to a corresponding stream in WSO2 CEP or WSO2 BAM. Then using the Siddhi queries (The underlying sql like query language of the event engine) a time windows can be defined that match the allowed duration the message should reach the next system.
Then within the same window construct of the Siddhi query the expired events could be compared for a matching event in the second stream. If there is no matching event in the second stream then we could send it to another stream where we can configure an output event adapter to send the alert. 
For more information please refer: 
http://eranga-wso2.blogspot.com/2015/02/wso2-complex-event-processor.html
http://eranga-wso2.blogspot.com/2015/02/configuring-email-event-adapter-in-wso2.html*